# When I specify my user name and password to the DriverManager.getConnection it returns an error saying I didn't use a password

Tags: java, mysql, passwords

I am trying to establish a connection to MySQL database but when I attempt to connect I get the error:

SQLException: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
SQLState: 28000
VendorError: 1045

This is the Java program I am attempting to get the connection with and I am providing a password to the DriverManager.getConnection.

```
//import java.sql.Connection;

//import java.sql.DriverManager;

//import java.sql.SQLException; 

import java.sql.*;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

public class jconnector_test{
   public static void main (String[] args) {

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //DriverManager.registerDriver (new Driver()); 
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
    System.out.println("Unable to load the driver class!" + x);
    }

    Connection conn = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    String user = "test";
    String password = "test";

    try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    //do something with the Connection                                                  
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
    // handle any errors
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
  }
}
```

SQLException: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
SQLState: 28000
VendorError: 1045